# Twitter API Endpoint Not working V2 and unauthorized

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

First, I want to display user tweets.
I am following this documentation on Twitter.

First step:
https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=aXY2M2NqWTlfNUxFNxxxxxQ&client_scret=xxxNkuYIWvNthjxxx&redirect_uri=https://example.com/&scope=tweet.tweet.ustate.2%state_read. lenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain

I am obtaining the code successfully.

Second step:
The code, grant_type, client_id, redirect_uri, and code_verifier are all valid.

Please see the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jLKL.png)

Why am I still receiving an error?
What am I doing wrong? Where is the problem?
Is the documentation I am following correct?

Thank you all very much.

I am using the free tier.

Where is the problem and how to solve the problem ?